# Need help performing the taylor series expansion for below-mentioned expression in square brackets

Tags: calculus

The Taylor series expansion result, limited to the first order term, for the expression
$$\left[1-\left(1+\frac{1}{y}\right)^\frac{1}{2}\right] = \left(\frac{1}{2y}\right)$$
Then right hand side is the result. Can someone show me the step/s, I do not know how to do this.
Thank you.

Comment: Can you please describe in more detail the trouble you are having? What did you try to do? Click "Edit" above rather than elaborating in the comments, thanks.

Comment: The first step is to find the Taylor series for $(1+(1/y))^{1/2}$. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: No, I do not know exactly how to do that. I obtained the first derivative, I believe, I only need that. After that I am not clear how to proceed.

Comment: Hint: the expression  $\sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{y}}$ can be simplified to  $\sqrt{\frac{y + 1}{y}}$ then express it as the reciprocal of the reciprocal which should be $\sqrt{\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\frac{y + 1}{y}}}}$. Now consider the taylor series of $\frac{1}{y + 1}.$

Comment: OK, you found the first derivative. Then do you know how to use it to find the beginning of the Taylor series?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everyone seems to have overlooked that in a Taylor series, the variable appears in the numerator, not the denominator. What you have is not the Taylor series of the function with respect to $y$, but instead with respect to $\frac 1y$.

That is, if you let $x = \frac 1y$, the function becomes $$f(x) = 1-\sqrt{1+x}$$ The Taylor series for this function begins with
$$f(x) = 0 - \frac12 x + \frac 18x^2 + \dots$$
Dropping the higher order terms and substituting $\frac 1y$ for $x$, we get

$$f\left(\frac 1y\right) \approx -\frac 1{2y}$$

Which is the result you should be after. The negation is correct, your version is not. For positive $y$, the function has a negative value.

Comment: Thank you very much for showing the steps to the answer. This is what I was looking for.